# Unable to Retrieve Key/Value Pairs From Bash Associative Array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

## TL;DR

I'm unable to retrieve the list of keys from an associative array in a bash
script.  However, when I attempt to write a simplified [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), everything
works as expected, and I can't tell what I'm doing differently between the two.

## Long Version

I'm writing a bash script which needs to read in a set of preferences from
an file and stores them in an associative array. Note that I'm using XML and
would prefer to use a Perl module to read the file, but the script will
be run on a large number of systems, most of which don't have the proper
Perl modules installed, and on almost none of which I have the necessary
access to install them.  Anyway, parsing the XML file is not the issue here.

The issue is that when I run the following script against the XML file,
the settings I'm reading in from the XML file appear to be saving to the
associative array.  In other words, the following code works as expected:

```
while read line
do
    # Trimming code that sets key-val.
    $config[$key]=$val
    echo "${key}=${config[$key]}"
done
```

But later in the script when I attempt to retrive the config values, nothing
appears to be there.  It appears that the config array is getting cleared
somehow, but I'm not clear where or how.

### xml_config.sh

Here's the non-working script.

```
#! /bin/bash

# Configuration Array.
declare -A config

CONFIG_XML=./config.xml

# Extract key-value pairs.
echo "Extracting and setting initial key-value pairs:"
grep "^.*<setting.*id=.*$" $CONFIG_XML |
while read line
do
    key=$(echo "${line}" | perl -pe "s|^.*id.*?=.*?[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"].*$|\1|")
    val=$(echo "${line}" | perl -pe "s|^.*value.*?=.*?[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"].*$|\1|")
    config[$key]="${val}"

    # This line prints key=value pairs as expected.
    echo "${key}=${config[$key]}"
done

# This loop does not print key=value pairs as expected.
echo -e "\n\nExtracting key-value pairs from associative array and printing:"
for key in "${!config[@]}"
do
    echo "${key}=${config[$key]}"
done

echo -e "\n\nAlso doesn't work:\nkey1=${config[key1]}"
```

### config.xml

This is the contents of the config.xml file that goes along with the script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <setting id="key1" value="val1" />
    <setting id="key2" value="val2" />
    <setting id="key3" value="val3" />
    <setting id="key4" value="val4" />
    <setting id="key5" value="val5" />
</config>
```

### Simplified MCVE

Here are the contents of my simplified [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which I expected to
fail, but which works as expected:

```
declare -A aa
for i in {0..10}
do
    key="KEY${i}"
    val="VAL${i}"
    aa[$key]=$val
done

for key in "${!aa[@]}"
do
    # Prints key-value pairs as expected.
    echo "${key}=${aa[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: Your `while` loop in your non-working code is executed in a subshell induced by the pipeline. The changes to the array only exist in that subshell. As an aside, do not process XML with `sed`; use a proper XML parser. `bash` probably is not the right choice for this script.

Comment: Well duh.  Please write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.  As far as processing XML with `sed` or other regex, I'm aware of the risks of doing that and prefer a `Perl` one-liner (or multi-liner) for this (`Python` would be better yet), but it needs to run on a large number of servers, many of which don't have the proper libraries, as far as I can tell, and I don't have the necessary access on most of them to install the libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop must execute in the current shell in order for the changes to the array to take effect. One solution is to use a process substitution instead of a pipe.

```
while read line
do
    key=$(echo "${line}" | perl -pe "s|^.*id.*?=.*?[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"].*$|\1|")
    val=$(echo "${line}" | perl -pe "s|^.*value.*?=.*?[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"].*$|\1|")
    config[$key]="${val}"

    # This line prints key=value pairs as expected.
    echo "${key}=${config[$key]}"
done < <(grep "^.*<setting.*id=.*$" $CONFIG_X)
```

If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, you can use the `lastpipe` option instead.

```
shopt -s lastpipe

grep "^.*<setting.*id=.*$" $CONFIG_XML | while read line; do
    ...
done
```